# Add data to the graph by a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, morris.js

I am using [this](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) plugin to play with charts; now, I just want to know how can I add data through a JSON string to this graph:

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

[JSBin Link](http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output)

I have tried to add data through a JSON string but getting a syntax error

```
var data-graph = "[{ y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },{ y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },{ y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },{ y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }]";


Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: data-graph,
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

Surely I am not giving data in an appropriate way. How can I add data by a variable or JSON string and what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: Don't you think "[{ }]" this not the JSON format

Comment: usually I would send JSON data as: { {"y": "2006", "a": "100", b: "90"}, {"y": "2007", "a": "75"}....} and so on

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing your string back to just an object? Remove the quotes.

```
var data-graph = [{ y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },{ y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },{ y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },{ y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },{ y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }];
```